# Caption does not work after centering image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

When I hovered on the image, some text would appear over that image. However, after centerizing it, something went wrong with positioning and the text caption is displayed a bit left of the image, it doesn't get centered too.

Below is my code, which contains several pieces of code found on the internet.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <p class="caption">
    <img class="profile_pic" src="img/spiropoulos.jpg" alt="spy" />
    <span>Rainbow and Tree</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div.clear { 
  clear: both; 
}
p.caption { 
  display: block !important; 
  position: relative !important;
}
p.caption img { 
  position: absolute !important
}
p.caption span { 
  background: #000; 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
  color: white !important; 
  display: none; 
  padding: 5px 10px !important; 
  text-align: center; 
  position: absolute !important;
  bottom: 0 !important; 
  left: 0 !important; 
  width: 100% !important;
}
p.caption span big {
  font-weight: bold; 
}
.profile_pic{
  height: 160px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

and the JS:

```
// this is to center the image
$("p.caption>img").each(function(i, img) {
    $(img).css({
        position : "relative",
        left : ($(img).parent().width() / 2) - ($(img).width() / 2)
    });
});

// this is for the caption
// For each instance of p.caption
$("p.caption>div").each(function() {
    $(this)
    // Add the following CSS properties and values
    .css({
        // Height equal to the height of the image
        "height" : $(this).children("img").height() + "px",
        // Width equal to the width of the image
        "width" : $(this).children("img").width() + "px"
    })
    // Select the child "span" of this p.caption
    // Add the following CSS properties and values
    .children("span").css(

    // Width equal to p.caption
    // But subtract 20px to callibrate for the padding
    "width", $(this).width() - 20 + "px")

    // find the <big> tag if it exists
    // And then add the following div to break the line
    .find("big").after('<div class="clear"></div>');

    // When you hover over p.caption
    $("p.caption>div").hover(function() {

        // Fade in the child "span"
        $(this).children("span").stop().fadeTo(400, 1);
    }, function() {
        // Once you mouse off, fade it out
        $(this).children("span").stop().delay(600).fadeOut(400);
    });
    // End $(this)
});
```

Expected result is something like this: http://css-plus.com/examples/2010/05/how-to-create-an-image-caption-with-jquery/

Comment: Since you are nesting a `div` in a `p`, which is not technically allowed by the HTML specification, the `p` tag is closed prematurely and your markup is not behaving as expected.  Replace the `p` with `div` and that might clear the issue.

Comment: I think you can do this mostly in CSS also... are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: `div` element is not valid child element for `p` element

Comment: @guest271314 you are talking about the JS code? That was my latest attempt, if I use `p.caption` only it won't work again.

Comment: @MarcAudet that was my first attempt. Yes I am using Bootstrap. However I failed to make it work that way. What exactly do you want me to replace?

Comment: @gsamaras Not yet attempted `js` . `html` `div` element is not valid child element for `<p>` element , see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p . As suggested by @MarcAudet , could be achieved using `css`

Comment: Then there is no way to find a solution for this I guess... @guest271314 should I delete the question? I replaced `div` for `p` but nothing happened.

Comment: Not certain if Question should be deleted ? Why would delete Question if not resolved ?  What is expected result ? "Rainbow and Tree" to be displayed over `<img class="profile_pic" src="img/spiropoulos.jpg" alt="spy" />` on hover of `img` parent element ?

Comment: I would keep the question open for a day, maybe make it clear that you would consider a CSS based answer with simpler JS, someone is bound to prevent a solution or two.

Comment: OK guys. I updated my question with the desired result.

Comment: @guest271314 and Marc check my update, I changed the code and now only the span is not centered with the picture.

Comment: Do you want a solution for a single image or multiple images (3 or 4 per width of screen)? The solution details may depend on the size and aspect ratio of the images.

Comment: I will have only one image on my page @MarcAudet, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
div img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
div h2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.0em 0; /*optional*/
  display: none;
}
div:hover h2 {
  display: block;
}

Here is one way of display a caption over an image using CSS only.
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature" />
  <h2>Some Caption Text</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `css` `:hover` , `:after`

```css
p:hover:after {
  content:"Rainbow and Tree";
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:11px;
  background:#000;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
  color:#fff;
  top:-4px;
  left:-99px;
  z-Index:1;
  opacity:.75;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature" />
</p>
```

Comment: No!!!! The title is suppose to be part of the content, hiding it in a pseudo element does not really make sense.

Comment: @MarcAudet _"No!!!! The title is suppose to be part of the content, hiding it in a pseudo element does not really make sense."_ ?

Comment: guest<numbers> I am going to accept Marc's answer, because the result is closer to what my code produces. For this reason I am going to upvote another good answer of yours too.

Comment: The image caption is actual content, which means it should appear in the DOM.  Pseudo elements are not part of the DOM, which means for example, those words would never be indexed by a search engine.  Pseuodo-elements should only contain text that is purely either decorative or optional.

Comment: @MarcAudet _"The image caption is actual content, which means it should appear in the DOM. Pseudo elements are not part of the DOM, which means for example, those words would never be indexed by a search engine. "_  Not certain how requirement was extended to include `DOM` element , or search engine indexing ? See OP at  _"When I hovered on the image, some text would appear over that image."_ appear to be actual requirement ? _"Pseuodo-elements should only contain text that is purely either decorative or optional. "_  ? Link to specification, documentation containing "should only contain"  ?

Comment: Your answer is technically correct, but in practice, it is not that useful.  The image caption is content that is part of the website, and it should be contained in the HTML mark-up, and not part of the CSS rules.  CSS rules are not considered to be content.

Comment: The following article talks about pseudo-elements and how to use them: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Comment: @MarcAudet _"Your answer is technically correct, but in practice, it is not that useful. The image caption is content that is part of the website, and it should be contained in the HTML mark-up, and not part of the CSS rules. CSS rules are not considered to be content"_ Not certain where _"should"_ portion of comments is based upon ? Original Question did not specify or require that _"some text would appear over that image"_ be `DOM` element , or "content". Not certain how these requirements have been surreptitiously included in requirement ?

Comment: @MarcAudet _"The following article talks about pseudo-elements and how to use them"_ ? Linked article http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/ is not specification ,  documentation , nor controlling technical data about `css` pseudo elements or pseudo classes . Again, not certain how _"should"_ portion of above comments is applicable to current Question , or can be substantiated by  `css` documentations , specifications ?