# Simulating behaviour of alt attribute of images

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the visitor hovers an image alt text appears. Is it possible to simulate this behaviour with javascript for any event and element?

Appending a small span in that point would be a solution but I want to know if this is possible without appending anything to the content.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) attribute

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to use this feature within canvas and change the text dynamically.

Comment: _"but I want to know if this is possible without appending anything to the content."_ See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33587727/caption-does-not-work-after-centering-image

Comment: Why yo don't want to alter the content? Have you looked at some jQuery plugins to create tooltips? As pointed by sharf you can use the title attribute on any element and you can modify it as you need.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution using `<figcaption>` to play the role of your on-hover tooltip.

Using `<figcaption>` as the tooltip will give additional semantic meaning to your markup.

```css
figure.inline-image,
figure.inline-image img {
display: inline-block;
width: 260px;
height: 150px;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

figcaption {
display: none;
position: relative;
top: -70px;
left: 40px;
padding: 3px;
width: auto;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 227, 1);
font-size: 12px;
}

figure.inline-image:hover figcaption {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<figure class="inline-image">
<img src="danish-flag.jpg" alt="Flag of Denmark" />
<figcaption>In the sky flies a red flag with a white cross whose vertical bar is shifted towards the flagpole.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

First check out the [title](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) attribute, it is very similar to the alt attribute.
In addition to that there here are events like `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. You can even have the data available on the element with the `data-alt` attribute.(you can replace alt with anything).

There are also numerous libraries available for this, but I'll show u a quickie.

```js
(function(){NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

var toolTip = document.createElement('DIV');
toolTip.style.display = "none";
toolTip.style.position = "absolute";
toolTip.style.width = "50px";
toolTip.style.height = "auto";
toolTip.style.border = "solid 1px black";
toolTip.style.transition = "top 50ms,left 50ms, display 500ms";
    function updatePosition(e){
      toolTip.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
      toolTip.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
    }
document.body.appendChild(toolTip);
document.querySelectorAll("[data-alt]").forEach(function(e){
  e.addEventListener('mouseenter',function(e){
    toolTip.style.display = "block";
    toolTip.style.cursor = "text";
    toolTip.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
    toolTip.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
    toolTip.textContent = this.getAttribute('data-alt');
  })
})
document.querySelectorAll("[data-alt]").forEach(function(e){

  e.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){    
       updatePosition(e)

  })
})
document.querySelectorAll("[data-alt]").forEach(function(e){
  e.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(e){
    toolTip.style.display = "none";
  })
})
})();
```

```html
<h2 class="space" data-alt="Hello">Your Answer</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to use `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements as described [here](http://jackosborne.com/articles/css-tooltips-with-the-pseudo-element/) in order to make CSS Tooltips.